# clickable hashtags in textview within a listview

Tags: android, listview, textview, clickable

I've been trying to implement a clickable hashtag within a textview feature within in my listview with the following functionality:

1.Clicking anywhere within a list item apart from the hashtag should register as a list item OnClick.

2.Clicking on the hashtag should launch a new activity

The problem I am having is that clicking on the remainder of the textview (not the hashtag) is not being detected as a List item click. How can I solve this?

I have used this example https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/176-how-to-implment-hashtags-and-callouts-in-android and many others but the whole textview seems to stop the listview from receiving clicks.

A good example is the twitter app with url links... how is this achievable with hashtags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, i found this exemple of lib that you can use to implement your listView with hashtags.
[HashTags Lib Android](https://github.com/rameshvoltella/Hash-Tags-Android)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an onItemClickListener for the listview within your fragment and then within your custom adapter setting onClickListener for the textview (or whatever view) that holds your hashtag?

```
Frament implements onItemClickListener

listView.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// action you want when people click on list item
}

//***************

Adapter implements onClickListener

textview.setOnClickListener(this)

public void onClick(View view) {
// action when hashtag is clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your root view

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"